Sequelize association loading error in aws serverless environment
I have problems loading the associations on serverless environment. I have defined all my sequelize associations in one single file and I load that file at the time of database connection. Now, sometimes it works, sometimes I get error saying Model X is not associated with model Y. To those, who have used sequelize on aws lambda, can you guide me how to load associations? Thanks.
Btw, I'm using serverless-http package.
